# Sound does not play while using AVAudioPlayer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, avaudioplayer

Here is my code on button click

```
- (void)playButton:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Play  Button Clicked!!!...");
    audioPlayer = [self setUpAudioPlayer:[songs objectAtIndex:i]];
}

-(AVAudioPlayer *)setUpAudioPlayer:(NSString *)filename
{
    NSLog(@"File name : %@",filename);

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:filename ofType:@"caf"]; 

    NSLog(@"File path = %@",path);

    AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:nil]; 

    //audioPlayer.volume = 0.5;
    [audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
    [audioPlayer play];
    NSLog(@"Song is playing....");

    return [audioPlayer autorelease];
}
```

here songs is NSMutableArray which contains file name... All things go correct with NSLog... But no sound is coming and no error comes..  What is wrong with the code..???

Comment: here audioplayer in button click is only Reference variable.. But i am getting instance variable from my method setUpAudioPlayer....

Comment: did you set delegate to its variable ? audioPlayer.delegate = self;

Comment: yes i have set delegate to audioPlayer.. but i got answer... thanx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your audio player is probably getting released as soon as it starts playing. Try to retain it after `setUpAudioPlayer` is called.

Comment: try to release it in - dealloc() method !

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you need to initialize an audio session, some like this

```
- (void)setupAudioSession
{

    AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    NSError *error = nil;

    [session setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error: &error];
    if (error != nil)
        NSLog(@"Failed to set category on AVAudioSession");

    // AudioSession and AVAudioSession calls can be used interchangeably
    OSStatus result = AudioSessionAddPropertyListener(kAudioSessionProperty_AudioRouteChange, RouteChangeListener, self);
    if (result) NSLog(@"Could not add property listener! %d\n", result);

    BOOL active = [session setActive: YES error: nil];
    if (!active)
        NSLog(@"Failed to set category on AVAudioSession");


}
```